# python 2 - why does 'with' behave differently in embedded c code?

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to use python 2.7.5 in a c/c++ DLL. This DLL is used by another application which has made debugging a challenge. After banging away at this for hours I have isolated the problem down to where a file read in a 'with' statement is throwing an exception. This I do not understand...'with' should absorb an exception if implemented correctly, right? Anyway calling the same python code from the command line has no problems at all.

My C/CPP DLL calls this...

```
def parsetest(filename):
     bytesin = getMD3Bytes(filename)
     return bytesin

def getMD3Bytes(filename):
     filename = 'lower.md3'
     bytes = ''
     valuetoreturn = 1
     try:
          with open(filename,'rb') as fileptr:
               if fileptr != None:
                    bytes = fileptr.read()
                    valuetoreturn = 333
     except:
          valuetoreturn = 991
     return valuetoreturn
```

If the DLL runs this code via...

```
pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, arguments);
```

And gets a result via...

```
iResult = PyInt_AsLong(pValue);
```

iResult has the value of 991 instead of 333 which would only happen if an exception had not occurred inside of 'with'. I know because I had the app calling the DLL pop up a message box with iResult in it.

Even more interesting to me, this works...

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\DeleD CE\Plugins>python
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import parseMD3
>>> testval = parseMD3.parsetest('junk')
>>> print testval
333
>>> exit()
```

So why does the CLI python return a different result that the same code being call from PyObject_CallObject? Why does 'with' behave differently here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with` does not handle exceptions. It only ensures that the file is closed when an exception occurs. If an exception occurs in the `open()` expression itself, the `with` block isn't even entered; `fileptr` will never be bound to `None` either.

You are catching **all** exceptions, including keyboard interrupts and memory errors, so we cannot begin to tell why the code fails when running under C++ control here.

Stick to a limited set of exceptions instead, like `IOError`, and log the exception properly:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('__name__')

def getMD3Bytes(filename):
    filename = 'lower.md3'
    bytes = ''
    valuetoreturn = 1
    try:
        with open(filename,'rb') as fileptr:
            bytes = fileptr.read()
            valuetoreturn = 333
    except IOError:
        logger.exception('Failed to open file properly')
        valuetoreturn = 991
    return valuetoreturn
```

The default config for the logger will output to `stderr`, but you can configure it to log to a file instead:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='/tmp/debug.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: You were correct...my misunderstanding of exactly what 'with' was doing was my problem. IOError was returning error code 2 (unable to find file). Fixed it by specifying "C:/Program Files (x86)/DeleD CE/Plugins/lower.md3" instead of "lower.md3".